# How to get the stack trace of a nested exeption in python?

Tags: python, exception, stack, traceback

If an exception is raised I'd like to analyse the stack trace in python that tells about where exactly the problem is in the source code file.

Of course for that purpose the module `traceback` exists. And that works fine for regular exceptions. But how do you deal with this situation if nested exceptions occur?

Consider this example:

```py
def test():
    try:
        a = 0
        b = 5 / a
    except Exception as ee1:
        assert False

test()
```

This example prints two exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test4d.py", line 12, in test
    b = 5 / a
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test4d.py", line 18, in <module>
    test()
  File "./test4d.py", line 14, in test
    assert False
AssertionError
```

So information about both exceptions is known to the interpreter. I therefore like to retrieve these two pieces of information from Python: The stack trace of the assert statement (used as an example here to cause an exception) and the stack trace of the division by zero exception (used as an example here to cause an exception). *How can I do that?*

And the second part of the question: How can I do that in a structured way? The module `traceback` can be used to get more information about an existing exception. But I do not want to print the exception, I want to store it. Therefore I'd like to get the stack trace as a tuple of instances of some class where each instance represents the data within each stack frame. How can I do *that*?

Comment: It does not answer the question you ask, but the [raise...from](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) pattern is the proper way to cause nested exceptions. (In your example, it looks to me as if ee1 should *not* be in the stacktrace, as it was caught.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Leporello. I experimented with it but could not find a way with it. But based on your comment I was now able to rephrased the question so it is now more precise. (The problem with *raise...from* is: I could not get access  to the previous stack trace for some reason. On re-raising an Exception  the old stack trace seems always to be lost.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable named `__context__` associated with an exception. This variable can be used to access nested exceptions. See this example:

```py
import traceback

def test():
    try:
        a = 0
        b = 5 / a
    except Exception as ee1:
        assert False

try:
    test()
except Exception as ee:
    print(repr(ee))
    stackTraceList = traceback.extract_stack(ee.__traceback__.tb_frame)
    del stackTraceList[0]
    for frame in stackTraceList:
        print("\t", frame)

    if ee.__context__:
        print(repr(ee.__context__))
        stackTraceList = traceback.extract_stack(ee.__context__.__traceback__.tb_frame)
        del stackTraceList[0]
        for frame in stackTraceList:
            print("\t", frame)
```

This will output the following text:

```
AssertionError()
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)
     <FrameSummary file ./example.py, line 8 in test>
```

That indicates that both exceptions can be identified and their stack traces can be iterated through.

For convenience I implemented a simple helper module to process exceptions and stack traces named `jk_exceptionhelper`. You can install this module using `pip`. For details have a look at the GIT repository: https://github.com/jkpubsrc/python-module-jk-exceptionhelper